# Can not run macro The macro may not be available in this workbook or all marcos may be disabled

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to ad a activity (in this example print time) after every 5 second by following code.

```
Sub tr1()
dim i as Integer
i = Range("b1").Value
If i < 3 Then
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "tr2", , True
End If

Range("a" & i).Value = UCase(Format(Now, "HH:MM:SS"))
Range("b1").Value = Range("b1").Value + 1
MsgBox ("tr1 called")
End Sub

Sub tr2()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "tr1"
MsgBox ("tr2 called")
End Sub
```

on running tr1, I am getting following error:

[image: Error screen shot] after 5 seconds. Please, let me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You are using the wrong filetype. You need a macro enabled workbook such as *.xlsm

Comment: @Tragamor .xlsb is a binary file type, which may contain macros.

Comment: Fair enough; I have never used .xlsb files so was unaware... Thanks @Olly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to refer the module as well. This will work, if the code is in `Module1`:

```
Sub tr1()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "!Module1.tr2", , True
End Sub

Sub tr2()
    MsgBox "tr2"
End Sub
```

If it is in a worksheet, the correspondingly:

```
Sub tr1()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "!Sheet1.tr2", , True
End Sub

Sub tr2()
    MsgBox "tr2"
End Sub
```